# Вывести в Activity в TextView сумму колонки из таблицы

Tags: android, android-room

Пишу приложение для учета доходов и расходов. Добавление расходов сделал. в Приложении `MainActivity` содержит `textView` (несколько штук), в которые выводятся общая сумма расходов за день, неделю и месяц. Пытаюсь пока что реализовать просто вывод в `TextView` всех расходов без учета периода.

Сделал вот так:

в интерфейсе CostsDao

```
@Dao
public interface CostsDao {
    @Insert
    void insert(Costs item);

    @Query("SELECT SUM(summ) FROM costs")
    double summ();

}
```

Класс добавления расходов или доходов

```
public class AddCostsIncomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CostsDao costsDao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_costs_income);

        costsDao = AppDatabase.getInstance(this).costsDao();
    }


    private void saveCostsOrIncome() {
        double summ = 7.0f; //Пока при каждом добавлении такая сумма. Для тестов
        Costs costs = new Costs(mills, summ, categoryID, currencyID, "comment");
        costsDao.insert(costs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_costs_income_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.actionSave:
                saveCostsOrIncome();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

в MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private CostsDao costsDao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ***

        costsDao = AppDatabase.getInstance(this).costsDao();

        holderCostsDay.setText(costsDao.summ() + "");
    }

}
```

Из `MainActivity` открывается другое активити, происходит само добавление расходов в БД. Как правильно реализовать обновление значения в `TextView` после добавления очередных расходов?

Сейчас когда добавляю новые расходы в `MainActivity` в `TextView` значение не изменяется, оно меняется только если перезайти, а хотелось бы чтобы при добавлении чтобы сразу обновилось.

Используется как уже вы поняли `Room`.

Comment: setText() в каком методе? А лучше побольше кода.

Comment: Обновил вопрос. setText в MainActivity, а само добавление в другом активити

Comment: Кажется вопрос умер(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам разобрался. Перенес строку `holderCostsDay.setText(costsDao.summ() + "");` в метод `onResume()`.

Answer (score 0):

после добавления новых расходов добавь -> textview.invalidate()